# onWindowFocusChanged not work in Lollipop?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the `onWindowFocusChanged` in application but they not support to lollipop.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.e(TAG, "onWindowFocusChanged, " + hasFocus);
    mWindowhasFocus = hasFocus;

}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29 - you do something wrong

Answer (score 1):

No, it's actually working on Lollipop (and even on Marshmallow - I checked).

[The documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29) about this method says:

> Called when the current Window of the activity gains or loses focus.
>   This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the
>   user. The default implementation clears the key tracking state, so
>   should always be called.

I wrote very simple one-Activity-test app:
`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView statusTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        statusTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        String newStatus = statusTextView.getText() + (hasFocus? "Got focus" : "Lost focus") + "\n";
        statusTextView.setText(newStatus);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So by moving app to the background back and forth, you can see how the state is changing.